# Can output of an ARM template be used in another template as a reference which is not called as nested?

Tags: azure, function, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

I'm trying to use different templates for creating a NSG and then for a spoke. I don't want to use nested template, instead I want the out of NSG template as resource ID and give reference to spoke template as a parameter. Can this be achieved or is it just the case for nested template also the parameters in the spoke template where NSG resource ID is needed is in a array as I have used copy function.

```
"outputs": {"resourceID": {
"type": "string",
"value": "[resourceId('Microsoft.Network/networkSecurityGroups', variables('nsgName'))]"}}
```

This output is to be used here

```
   "subnetsConfiguration": {
        "value": [
            {
                "name": "app-subnet",
                "addressPrefix": "10.112.0.0/20",
                "networkSecurityGroupName": "set the resource ID as a reference here",
```

Comment: The "arm" tag is for the ARM microprocessor architecture, not for Azure Resource Manager. I've fixed it. Please be careful with the use of tags.

Comment: @Codo my bad. Sure I'll be careful

Answer (score 0):

To get an output value from a linked template, retrieve the property value with syntax like: `[reference('deploymentName').outputs.propertyName.value]`

First, the linked template- helloworld.json

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {},
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [],
    "outputs": {
        "greetingMessage": {
            "value": "Hello World",
            "type" : "string"
        }
    }
}
```

The main template deploys the linked template and gets the returned value -

```
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {},
    "variables": {},
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Resources/deployments",
            "apiVersion": "2020-06-01",
            "name": "linkedTemplate",
            "properties": {
                "mode": "incremental",
                "templateLink": {
                    "uri": "[uri(deployment().properties.templateLink.uri, 'helloworld.json')]",
                    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0"
                }
            }
        }
    ],
    "outputs": {
        "messageFromLinkedTemplate": {
            "type": "string",
            "value": "[reference('linkedTemplate').outputs.greetingMessage.value]"
        }
    }
}
```

Please refer this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/linked-templates?tabs=azure-powershell#get-values-from-linked-template) for more details.